# Textbox value changed

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

Is it possible to know if any of the textbox values have changed in the application.
  I have around 30 textboxes and I want to run a part of code only if, any of the textboxes value has changed out of the 30. Is there a way I can know that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each text box will raise an event [`TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) when it's contents have changed. However, that requires you to subscribe to each and every event.

The good news is that you can subscribe to the event with the same method multiple times. The handler has a parameter `sender` which you can use to determine which of your 30 text boxes has actually raised the event.

You can also use the [GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus.aspx) and [LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus.aspx) events to keep track of actual changes. You would need to store the original value on `GotFocus` and then compare to the current value on `LostFocus`. This gets round the problem of two `TextChanged` events cancelling each other out.

Comment: If using MVVM + Binding there is no easy way to do this in WPF as the Binding class (which is perfectly placed to detect edits-in-progress) does not ...

Answer (score 2):

You can assign an event handler to each of the TextBox's TextChanged events.  All of them can be assigned to the same event handler in code.  Then you'll know when the text changes.  You can set a boolean flag field in your class to record that a change occurred.

Answer (score 1):

try this. Add this code to the load/constructor. no need to specify the event in the XAML explicitly

```
this.AddHandler(TextBox.TextChangedEvent, new TextChangedEventHandler(TextChanged));
private void TextChanged(object Sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //ToDO (use sender to identify the actuale text from where it fired }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps on the rough and ready side, but I did it this way.

In the constructor, I created

bool bChanged = false;

In the TextChanged event handler of each control (actually same for each), I put

bChanged = true;

When appropriate, I could do some processing, and set bChanged back to false.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just do this:

In your Constructor:

```
MyTextBox.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler( TextChanged );
```

And Then this Method:

```
private void TextChanged(object Sender, TextChangedEventArgs e){
            //Do something
        }
```