# control numeric textbox's numeric value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `TextBox` and I want it to be numeric only. Thus, I googled and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505008/numeric-textbox-in-c-sharp-wpf) stackoverflow post which helped me already a lot. However, I want the, now numeric only, textbox to show a warning when I enter something underneath 20. At first, I tried the event `OnTextInput`, and after no success I tried to handle it in the same event as the numeric stuff `OnPreviewTextInput`. I used the same code for both.

```
if (!char.IsDigit(e.Text, e.Text.Length - 1))
{
    var text = e.Text;
    int num;

    var success = int.TryParse(text, out num);
    if (!success)
        return;

    if (num <= 20)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to go underneath 20?",
                            "... You sure?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation) ==
                        MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                          e.Handled = true;

         else
         {
            num++;
            textBox.Text = num.ToString();
         }
    }

                e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: you say the number must not go below 20, but then you have a comparison: num <= 20   This includes 20. If it is okay for your textbox to hold "20", then you will want to remove the = sign from that comparison. (This comment is because your title and your code doesn't completely match up)

Comment: Yes I want 20 to be still ok

Comment: i believe this post will also help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587602/textbox-value-changed   It talks about a TextChanged event for TextBox, so you probably can do something like - On TextChanged get TextBox value, make sure it is a number, if so. Make sure it is greater than or equal to 20 (or if it is less than 20 do X)

Comment: Why don't you use NumericTextBox?

Answer (score 1):

Use [TextChanged Handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)
to catch when it changes, then make the filter.

Following your implementation can looks like this:

```
private void yourTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsDigit(e.Text, e.Text.Length - 1))
        {
            var text = e.Text;
            int num;

            var success = int.TryParse(text, out num);
            if (!success)
                return;

            if (num <= 20)
            {
                if (
                    MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to go underneath 20?",
                        "... You sure?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation) ==
                    MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                    e.Handled = true;
                else
                {
                    num++;
                    textBox.Text = num.ToString();
                }
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Something I totally missed was the fact that whenever somebody now writes 75%, the 7 is handled, too, which thus means I can't enter ANY number without notice... Any idea? :-O

Comment: @John what about checking first if `yourTextBox.Text.Length>1`

Comment: @Pikoh then I can't handle if input is 3, which is also forbidden

Comment: Yes, you can. But anyway,this seems a poor design to me,and difficult to implement. I suggest you use any number specific control instead of a textbox,and check the values when validating the control or the form

Comment: I agree with @Pikoh. Even if you wanna do it like this, treat it as a number not a char.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you handle the `KeyDown` event instead?

```
private void txtNumeric_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)  
 {  
    e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar); 
    if (Int32.Parse(sender.Text) <= 20)
        {
           if (
                MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to go underneath 20?",
                    "... You sure?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation) ==
                MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                e.Handled = true;
            else
            {
                num++;
                textBox.Text = num.ToString();
            }

 }
```

Comment: Because apparently there is none

Comment: Sorry didn't see the WPF tag. Updated answer to use `KeyDown`