# How to restirct user from entering Space in Textbox C#

Tags: c#

I want to restrict the user from entering space in textbox here in my code it simply gets the first input then check if it is space. What I want to do is in the whole text the user can't enter space in textbox

```
    private void txtPassword_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as TextBox).SelectionStart == 0)
            e.Handled = (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space);
        else
            e.Handled = false;
    }
```

Comment: winform or webform?

Comment: use the [`.Validating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating) event, because typinig is not the only way to change text.

Comment: Windows Form...

Answer (score 1):

you need to use textbox changed event for prevent copy paste white spaces

```
    private void txtPassword_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtPassword.Text.Contains(" "))
        {
            txtPassword.Text = txtPassword.Text.Replace(" ", "");
            txtPassword.SelectionStart = txtPassword.Text.Length;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can still paste a space through the clipboard, or drag text containing space into the box. See Slai's comment on the original question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587602/textbox-value-changed onchange would be a better even to catch all forms of input on the textbox